# Lateinit property mScrollView has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

I don't understand why I have this kind of error :

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mScrollView has not been initialized
```

I mean I have this kind of code :

```
@BindView(R.id.scroll_view)
lateinit var mScrollView: ScrollView
```

And here you can find on onCreateView

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_delete_account_reason, container, false)

    mUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view)
    ViewUtils.setupUI(view, activity)
    hideNextBtnOnKeyboardOpens(mScrollView, mNextBtn)

    setupLayout()
    mPresenter.getReasonKeyOfDeleteAccount()

    return view
}

private fun setupLayout() {
    mScrollView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        val r = Rect()
        mScrollView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r)
        val screenHeight = mScrollView.rootView.height
        val keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom

        if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15 && mInput.hasFocus()) { // Keyboard is visible
            val bottom = mNbCharactersMax.getBottom() + mNbCharactersMax.getPaddingBottom()
            val sy = mScrollView.scrollY
            val sh = mScrollView.height
            val delta = bottom - (sy + sh)
            mScrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, delta)
        }
    }
}
```

You can find here my xml.
All other ID work (everyID match) but I have only a problem with scrollView, I dont know why. If I remove ScrollView, everything will work but I need this.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/general_padding"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/delete_account_next"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delete_account_description"
            fontPath="fonts/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/general_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/general_padding"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/general_padding"
            android:letterSpacing="@dimen/general_letter_spacing"
            android:text="@string/delete_account_reason_description"
            android:textColor="@color/vision"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix,SpUsage" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/delete_account_radio_group"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/two_third_padding"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/two_third_padding"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/delete_account_description">

        </RadioGroup>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/delete_account_input_reason_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/delete_account_reason_specify_hint"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/general_padding"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/delete_account_radio_group">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/delete_account_input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fontPath="fonts/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf"
                tools:ignore="MissingPrefix,SpUsage"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:textColor="@color/jiren"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delete_account_reason_nb_caracters"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fontPath="fonts/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/delete_account_input_reason_layout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/delete_account_reason_nb_caracters_max"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/quarter_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/wolverine"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:letterSpacing="@dimen/general_letter_spacing"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingPrefix,SpUsage"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delete_account_reason_nb_caracters_max"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fontPath="fonts/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/delete_account_input_reason_layout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/general_padding"
            android:text="@string/delete_account_reason_specify_max_characters"
            android:textColor="@color/wolverine"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:letterSpacing="@dimen/general_letter_spacing"
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix,SpUsage"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>

<Button
    style="?borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:id="@+id/delete_account_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/half_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/half_padding"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/one_half_padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/one_half_padding"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/double_padding"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/one_half_padding"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
    android:letterSpacing="@dimen/general_letter_spacing"
    android:text="@string/delete_account_next_label"
    android:enabled="false"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    fontPath="fonts/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix,SpUsage"/>
```

do you understand why ?

Comment: You did not initialize `mScrollView`. You only declared it as lateinit.

Comment: I think Better Knife isn't good way to bind views in Kotlin, try kotlin synthetic instead.

Comment: Just in case: check that you have view with id `scroll_view` in `fragment_delete_account_reason.xml`

Comment: I will try to change the Id

Comment: @AlainProfessional you dont need to change the id, they just should match in fragment_delete_account_reason.xml and `@BindView(R.id.scroll_view)`

Comment: its match. In fact I have a lot of BindView in this find, and all id match.
Only ScrollView has a problem

Comment: Could you post `fragment_delete_account_reason` file?

Comment: Id of your view in XML is `delete_account_scroll_view` and you try to bind `scroll_view`.

Comment: @anber, I just try to change the ID, but I fail the copy paste. here you can find my real xml

Comment: @forpas found the solution.
For some reason the binding is not working for only "ScrollView". So i have to change the way to initialize it by : 

private lateinit var mScrollViewOfDeleteAccount: ScrollView
then 
mScrollViewOfDeleteAccount = view.findViewById(R.id.delete_account_scroll_view) 

instead of 
@BindView(R.id.delete_account_scroll_view
lateinit var mScrollViewOfDeleteAccount: ScrollView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `onCreateView()` initialize `mScrollView`:

```
mScrollView = view.findViewById<ScrollView>(R.id.scroll_view)
setupLayout()
```

Comment: You are getting an error, right? This means that mScrollView is not initialized.

Comment: Are you sure the id is scroll_view?

Comment: And fragment_delete_account_reason contains this view?

Comment: the id is scroll_view, i will try to change the id

Comment: Is there a case that you have this id `scroll_view` in other activities, fragments too?

Comment: Yes I do, thats why I change the Id by delete_account_scroll_view xml kotlin and xml but its still not working

Comment: Did you remove the Butterknife binding?

Comment: I dont think the problem is ButterKnife because all other id work except scrollview. But I already removed yes

Comment: If you removed it, check the variable `mScrollView` right after findViewById(). It can't be null if it belongs in the inflated layout.

Comment: i just retry to put
mScrollView = view.findViewById<ScrollView>(R.id.scroll_view) and its work, thank you !

Comment: @AlainProfessional fine. I don't use this kind of binding and I guess I won't.

Comment: Currently I didnt find a solution, I dont know why its not working

Comment: Do you check after findViewById() if mScrollView is null?

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can also use Kotlin extensions to do view bindings. Configure the dependency in your gradle follow this [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)

Then, import your layout views ids by using `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout>.*`
You'll get rid of Butterknife and you'll have your views always bound in the code without any findviewbyids or @BindViews annotations

Answer (score 0):

I suggest get rid of ButterKnife in Android with Kotlin cause it has inbuild `synthetic` feature. 
In your case you can use view with name `scroll_view` directly in your code:

```
private fun setupLayout() {
    scroll_view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        val r = Rect()
        scroll_view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r)
        val screenHeight = scroll_view.rootView.height
        val keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom

        if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15 && mInput.hasFocus()) { // Keyboard is visible
            val bottom = mNbCharactersMax.getBottom() + mNbCharactersMax.getPaddingBottom()
            val sy = scroll_view.scrollY
            val sh = scroll_view.height
            val delta = bottom - (sy + sh)
            scroll_view.smoothScrollBy(0, delta)
        }
    }
}
```

Of cause `scroll_view` is not Java/Kotlin name convention so you can rename it in XML to something like `scrollView` and you don't require class variable at all.
You just need an import something like `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.main_activity.*` but IDE will generate it automatically.